# spring boot sort by parameter or pathvariable

Tags: java, rest, sorting, spring-boot

I am using QueryDSL with Spring boot to retrieve records from database. I am able to sort the records by specifying the column name ("applicantid") like below:

```
@GetMapping("/applicants")
@ResponseBody
public Iterable<Applicant> getAllApplicants(@QuerydslPredicate(root = Applicant.class) Predicate predicate, @PageableDefault(sort = { "applicantid"}, value = 25) Pageable pageable) {
return this.applicantService.getAllApplicants(predicate, pageable);
}
```

But I want to sort by a parameter and pass it to the sort field (which can be applicantid, applicantname, etc - column fields). How to do it? I am not able to find proper syntax:

```
@GetMapping("/applicants/{sortBy}")
@ResponseBody
public Iterable<Applicant> getAllApplicants(@QuerydslPredicate(root = Applicant.class) Predicate predicate, @PathVariable(value = "sortBy") String sortBy
@PageableDefault(sort = sortBy, value = 25) Pageable pageable) {
return this.applicantService.getAllApplicants(predicate, pageable);
}
```

Only one column sorting is fine. If you can suggest with multiple column sorting that's great too. Please help me out. I am stuck at sorting. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You are setting by which attribute you want to sort in

```
@PageableDefault(sort = sortBy, value = 25) Pageable pageable) . . .
```

Instead of setting on your own, ask the client to send with which parameter you want to sort. So, your request would be like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/applicants?sort=applicantId&applicantId.dir=desc&size=25
```

This is equivalent to `Pageable(sort = applicantId, Order = SortOrder.DESC, value =25)`

You can pass multiple sorting params as well.

If you explicitly want to control over sort param, you can do like this:

```
    @GetMapping("/applicants/{sortBy}")
    @ResponseBody
    public Iterable<Applicant> getAllApplicants(@QuerydslPredicate(root = Applicant.class) Predicate predicate,
                                                @PathVariable(value = "sortBy") String sortBy,
                                                Pageable pageable) {
        Sort sort = pageable.getSort();
        if (sort != null) {
            sort = new Sort(sortBy, "other params");
        }
        pageable = new PageRequest(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize(), sort);

        return this.applicantService.getAllApplicants(predicate, pageable);
    }
```